# Access to XMLHttpRequest from origin has been blocked by CORS policy ( Vue.JS app calling Lumen App )

Tags: vue.js, cors, lumen

I'm using a Vue.JS application that is calling an API built with Lumen.
I'm always getting the below error whenever the Vue.JS app calls the Lumen API.

[image]

Below is a middleware used for CORS in Lumen.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //Intercepts OPTIONS requests
        if($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = response('', 200);
        } else {
            // Pass the request to the next middleware
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        // Adds headers to the response
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        // Sends it
        return $response;
    }
}
```

I have this added in the .htaccess file of lumen in **public** folder

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 1**
the ajax request header from chrome's network tab:-

[image]

I'm using:

> PHP Version: 5.6
>
> Development Environment: Homestead (Apache)

Comment: Seems like the origin is set to `*, *` but it should be only a single asterisk. Is the response header somewhere else modified? You should also never use an asterisk in production, except when you want to allow every website to make calls to your API.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3
Hello bro, sorry didn't get your point, what are the recommended actions you suggest ?

Comment: Go to the `Network` tab in the Chrome DevTools, then click onto the request and on the tab `Headers` you'll see the `Response Headers`. The header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be a single value: either `*` or `https://yourdomain.com`. It seems like this value is set to `*, *` somewhere in the back-end. It might be that setting the header in the `.htaccess` file and also in PHP leads to this invalid comma-separated header. You need to fix this, then it should be working.

Comment: Remove the 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"' from the .htaccess file. You’re already setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your PHP code. So when you also set in the .htaccess file, the response that gets sent back ends up having two Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers — both with the value '\*'.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3

Please check the screenshot I added in the question.

Comment: @sideshowbarker

Please check the screenshot I added for the header of the ajax request, I already removed that header from .htaccess but getting the same.

Comment: How about the actual call (just the next request)? Not the `OPTIONS` pre-flight?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3
The actual request is not instantiated, this is weird.

Comment: That means, that the browser denies the request because of the information he received in the `OPTIONS` call. The weird part is rather, that the header mentioned in the console message is different from the actual received header. Are you sure, that this is the request, that is actually failing and printing to the console? And it still prints the same message with `*, *`?

Comment: It is solved now after adding
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
instead of 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

in the CORS middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Solved now after adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

instead of

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

in the CORS middleware.